# SqlResultSetMapping in POJO

Tags: java, spring-data

I have a simple POJO:

I'm trying to map title column to title field:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "ownerSaleMapping",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = OwnerSale.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "title", type = String.class)
                        }
                )
        }
)

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "ownerSaleReport", query = "SELECT title FROM content where id=:contentId", resultSetMapping = "ownerSaleMapping")
public class OwnerSale {

    public OwnerSale() {
    }

     private String title;

    public OwnerSale(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

My repository interface:

```
public interface OwnerSaleRepository extends JpaRepository<OwnerSale, Long> {

    List<OwnerSale> ownerSaleReport(@Param("contentId") Long ownerId);
}
```

But when i'm using that:

```
List<OwnerSale> sales = ownerSaleRepository.ownerSaleReport(6);
```

I got this error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class domain.owner.OwnerSale
```

But i need to `OwnerSale` be a `POJO` not an `Entity`.

what is the solution?

Comment: actually I'm not sure that you can use not-Entity class here `JpaRepository<OwnerSale, Long>`

Comment: AFAIK adding annotation don't force class to become not POJO [link](https://spring.io/understanding/POJO). And it's strange that you can add `@SqlResultSetMapping` and `@NamedNativeQuery` but can't add `@Entity` and `@Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't turn your object to `Entity`, then maybe it's easier to use `JdbcTemplate` with simple `RowMapper`?

```
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate; //it depends on your config how to get it here.

List<OwnerSale> ownerSaleReport(Long ownerId){
    String sql = "SELECT title FROM content where id=:contentId"
    return jdbcTemplate.query(StringUtils.replaceEach(sql,
               new String[]{":contentId"},
               new String[]{ownerId.toString()}),
               (rs, i) -> {
                   OwnerSale ownerSale = new OwnerSale();
                   ownerSale.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));//(or using constructor)
                   return ownerSale;
               });
}
```

Here I use `StringUtils` from Apache but you can use any other way to pass args to `String`